# Enable/disable button based on text input in Blazor Server Side

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a simple Blazor Server app and would like to enable a button when there is text in an input, and disable the button if there is no text in the input.  I have looked at and tried numerous examples, and have not come up with a working solution yet. This is for a page with a search button, which requires valid text before the search button becomes enabled.

So, when as a user enters a character in the text input, button is enable.  If the user deletes all the text in the input, button is disabled.

Here is the simplified code:

```html
@page "/InputExample"

<h3>Input Example</h3>

<input type="text" @onkeyup="@(e => EnableButton(e))" @bind="myInputText" />

@if (disableState == true)
{
    <input type="button" value="I'm disabled" disabled="@buttonState">
}
else
{
    <input type="button" value="I'm not disabled">
}

@code 
{
    private string buttonState = "disabled";
    private string myInputText = "";
    bool disableState = true;

    public void EnableButton(EventArgs args)
    {
        if (myInputText.Length == 0)
        {
            disableState = true;
        }
        else
        {
            disableState = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is happening? Is it always disabled, or always enabled? Is `EnableButton()` being executed on keyup?

Comment: EnableButton() is being executed. But the myInputText.Length is always zero. So, on initialize the button is set to disabled, then any keypress triggers the EnableButton(). Since the myInputLength is always zero the button is always disabled. Interestingly, if you run it in the debugger, myInputLength does increment, but it is always one value behind the actual length

Comment: If JavaScript is necessary, I can deal with that. I just have not found a working JavaScript solution or example to this issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very experienced with Blazor yet and I don't know if this will work, but I can't say this in a comment, so....

Use `@bind:event="oninput"` so that the event fires on change instead of on loss of focus.

Get rid of the event handler and use `set` in the bound property to set `disabledState`.

Also, you could use the code you have and just see if calling `StateHasChanged()` in the handler does the trick.

```
@page "/InputExample"

<h3>Input Example</h3>

<input type="text" @bind:event="oninput" @bind="myInputText" />

@if (disableState == true)
{
    <input type="button" value="I'm disabled" disabled>
}
else
{
    <input type="button" value="I'm not disabled">
}

@code 
{
    bool disableState = true;

    private string _myInputText;
    public string myInputText { 
       get{ return _myInputText;} 
       set{ 
          _myInputText = value;
          disableState = _myInputText?.Length < 1 ? true : false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code worked beautifully.  The only thing I modified was to Trim() _myInputText before the disableState = line, did not work inline on that line.  I am very grateful.  I hope this can help someone else, because it was a thorn in my side for several days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not very familiar with the Blazor, but if you want to achieve this by regular JavaScript in your Blazor app, you can add the function to .cshtml file (_Host.cshtml)

**JS function:**

```
function changeValue() {
    var edValue = document.getElementById("myInputId");
    var s = edValue.value;
    if (s.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        document.getElementById("myBtn").value = "I'm disabled";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").removeAttribute("disabled");
        document.getElementById("myBtn").value = "I'm not disabled";
    }
}
```

And then can use it on .razor page e.g (Index.razor)

**Index.razor**

```
<input id="myInputId" type="text" onInput="changeValue()">
<input type="button" id="myBtn" value="I'm disabled" disabled="">
```